# go: randomly terminate pods in kubernetes cluster

Tags: go, ssh, terminal, kubernetes, cluster-computing

I would like to randomly shut down pods in a kubernetes cluster with go. I already wrote code, which enables to login to the server and run code.

Now I would need to read all the available pods in the cluster, choose some randomly and terminate them. *(I am new to go)*

Could you please help me doing this?

This is how I am running commands on the cluster/server
  `cli.ExecuteCmd("kubectl get pods")`

```
// Use one connection per command.
// Catch in the client when required.
func (cli *SSHClient)ExecuteCmd(command string){
  conn, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", cli.Hostname+":22", cli.Config)
  if err!=nil {
    logrus.Infof("%s@%s", cli.Config.User, cli.Hostname)
    logrus.Info("Hint: Add you key to the ssh agent: 'ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa'")
    logrus.Fatal(err)
  }
  session, _ := conn.NewSession()
  defer session.Close()
  var stdoutBuf bytes.Buffer
  session.Stdout = &stdoutBuf
  err = session.Run(command)
  if err != nil {
    logrus.Fatalf("Run failed:%v", err)
  }
  logrus.Infof(">%s", stdoutBuf.Bytes())
}
```

Comment: Which part are you struggling with?

Comment: I do not know how to write the function that randomly selects pods.

Comment: Because I would have to read them first and then randomly select them

Comment: try to connect list this. https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/examples/create-update-delete-deployment/main.go

Answer (score 1):

Use `k8s.io/client-go` ([Github Link](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go)) client package to list kubernetes pods, and then delete them randomly.

Use [client.CoreV1().Pods()](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/kubernetes/typed/core/v1/pod.go#L35) methods to list and delete pods.